# Uri of files in assets

Tags: android

I am using the `RingtoneManager` to play sounds. Everything
works ok when I store sound files (.mp3) in the appropriate SD directories.

I find out the URI of the file and I give it to `RingtoneManager` to play.

```
sd_uri = Uri.parse( "/sdcard/media/path/to/file" );
Ringtone rt = RingtoneManager.getRingtone( getApplicationContext(), sd_uri );
rt.play();
```

Just wondering what to do in case of tablets that do not come with an SD card.
My idea is to store sound files in `res/raw` or `res/assets` dirs, but unlike `MediaPlayer` that accepts resource identifiers, `RingtoneManager` only wants Uri.
How do I get the Uri of files in `res/raw` or `res/assets` dir?
Ideally I would use `res/raw`, to get  `R.raw.*` identifier, which might be handy.

Answer (score 0):

Do not hardcode path as `/sdcard` use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` instead. This will remove the dependency on sdcard.

Answer (score 0):

In my application I'm referencing to application **res/asset** located media file using URI like:

```
private static final String PLACEHOLDER="file:///android_asset/sample_video.3gp";
```

Comment: That will only work within the same application; other apps don't have access to files within the assets folder, unless (I believe) you write a custom content provider for them that makes them public.